# Unable to install v8js & v8 on Centos

Tags: centos7, v8, libv8, v8js

We've been trying to install v8js on our server:

**SERVER DETAILS**:

*Operating System: CentOS Linux 7 (Core)
CPE OS Name: cpe:/o:centos:centos:7
Kernel: Linux 3.10.0-042stab141.3
Architecture: x86-64*

We use php 7.4

We have tried numerous methods found online including using WHM, this is where the faults occur though:

*(in terminal ...)*

```
    **ea-php74-pecl install v8js**
```

which outputs:

```
    ''' downloading v8js-2.1.2.tgz ...
    Starting to download v8js-2.1.2.tgz (102,977 bytes)
    ........................done: 102,977 bytes
    28 source files, building
    running: phpize
    Configuring for:
    PHP Api Version:         20190902
    Zend Module Api No:      20190902
    Zend Extension Api No:   320190902
    Please provide the installation prefix of libv8 [autodetect] :
    building in /root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootl3thYo/v8js-2.1.2
    running: /root/tmp/pear/v8js/configure --with-php-config=/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/bin/php-config --with-v8js
    checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
    checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
    checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
    checking for pkg-config... /bin/pkg-config
    checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
    checking for cc... cc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables...
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
    checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
    checking for icc... no
    checking for suncc... no
    checking for system library directory... lib
    checking if compiler supports -R... no
    checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
    checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    checking for PHP prefix... /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr
    checking for PHP includes... -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/include/php -I/opt/cpanel/ea-        php74/root/usr/include/php/main -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/include/php/Zend -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/include/php/ext -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
    checking for PHP extension directory... /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules
    checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/include/php
    checking if debug is enabled... no
    checking if zts is enabled... no
    checking for gawk... gawk
    checking for V8 Javascript Engine... yes, shared
    checking for V8 files in default path... found in /usr/local
    found in /usr
    checking for g++... g++
    checking whether we are using the GNU C++ compiler... yes
    checking whether g++ accepts -g... yes
    checking how to run the C++ preprocessor... g++ -E
    checking for C standard version... c++11
    checking how to allow c++11 narrowing...
    **checking for libv8_libplatform... configure: error: could not find libv8_libplatform library
    ERROR: `/root/tmp/pear/v8js/configure --with-php-config=/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/bin/php-config --with-v8js' failed ''**'
```

**And we also tried 'ea-php74-pecl install v8', which outputs:**

```
    downloading v8-0.2.2.tgz ...
    Starting to download v8-0.2.2.tgz (199,055 bytes)
    ....................done: 199,055 bytes
    122 source files, building
    running: phpize
    Configuring for:
    PHP Api Version:         20190902
    Zend Module Api No:      20190902
    Zend Extension Api No:   320190902
    building in /root/tmp/pear/pear-build-root1CuGGg/v8-0.2.2
    running: /root/tmp/pear/v8/configure --with-php-config=/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/bin/php-config
    checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
    checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
    checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
    checking for pkg-config... /bin/pkg-config
    checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
    checking for cc... cc
    checking whether the C compiler works... yes
    checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
    checking for suffix of executables...
    checking whether we are cross compiling... no
    checking for suffix of object files... o
    checking whether we are using the GNU C compiler... yes
    checking whether cc accepts -g... yes
    checking for cc option to accept ISO C89... none needed
    checking how to run the C preprocessor... cc -E
    checking for icc... no
    checking for suncc... no
    checking for system library directory... lib
    checking if compiler supports -R... no
    checking if compiler supports -Wl,-rpath,... yes
    checking build system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    checking host system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    checking target system type... x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
    checking for PHP prefix... /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr
    checking for PHP includes... -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/include/php -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/include/php/main -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/include/php/TSRM -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/include/php/Zend -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/include/php/ext -I/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/include/php/ext/date/lib
    checking for PHP extension directory... /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules
    checking for PHP installed headers prefix... /opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/include/php
    checking if debug is enabled... no
    checking if zts is enabled... no
    checking for gawk... gawk
    checking for V8 Javascript Engine... yes, shared
    checking Check for supported PHP versions... supported (7.4.25)
    checking for V8 files in default path... found in /usr
    checking for ICU data file icudtl.dat... checking for V8 version... cat: /usr/include/v8-        version.h: No such file or directory
    cat: /usr/include/v8-version.h: No such file or directory
    cat: /usr/include/v8-version.h: No such file or directory
    cat: /usr/include/v8-version.h: No such file or directory
    cat: /usr/include/v8-version.h: No such file or directory
    /root/tmp/pear/v8/configure: line 4081: test: -gt: unary operator expected
    /root/tmp/pear/v8/configure: line 4082: test: -gt: unary operator expected
    ..
    ****configure: error: libv8 must be version 6.6.313 or greater****
    ERROR: `/root/tmp/pear/v8/configure --with-php-config=/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/bin/php-config' failed
```

Any ideas please? We have spent days trying to get this running...

**EDIT**:
[These](https://velenux.wordpress.com/2018/04/17/how-to-compile-and-install-v8-and-v8js-on-centos-7/) instructions are the ones we've been following, as well as [these](https://github.com/phpv8/v8js/blob/php7/README.Linux.md).

I've managed to fix the error indicating that it couldn't find the libv8_libplatform library by adding [this](https://chromium.googlesource.com/v8/v8/+/refs/heads/main/include) directory to the server.
So, now when I try to run:

```
ea-php74-pecl install v8js
```

I'm getting this error instead:

```
downloading v8-0.2.2.tgz ...
Starting to download v8-0.2.2.tgz (199,055 bytes)
...........done: 199,055 bytes
122 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20190902
Zend Module Api No:      20190902
Zend Extension Api No:   320190902
building in /root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootZge4Us/v8-0.2.2
running: /root/tmp/pear/v8/configure --with-php-config=/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/bin/php-config
checking for grep that handles long lines and -e... /bin/grep
checking for egrep... /bin/grep -E
checking for a sed that does not truncate output... /bin/sed
checking for pkg-config... /bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for cc... cc
checking whether the C compiler works... yes
checking for C compiler default output file name... a.out
checking for suffix of executables...
checking whether we are cross compiling... configure: error: in `/root/tmp/pear/pear-build-rootZge4Us/v8-0.2.2':
configure: error: cannot run C compiled programs.
If you meant to cross compile, use `--host'.
See `config.log' for more details
ERROR: `/root/tmp/pear/v8/configure --with-php-config=/opt/cpanel/ea-php74/root/usr/bin/php-config' failed
```

Answer (score 0):

The message `error: libv8 must be version 6.6.313 or greater` indicates that whatever V8 you have installed is too old. [Looks like](https://centos.pkgs.org/7/epel-x86_64/v8-3.14.5.10-25.el7.x86_64.rpm.html) CentOS 7 officially only offers 3.14, which is waaaaay outdated.

From a quick look, it seems that the [v8js instructions](https://github.com/phpv8/v8js/blob/php7/README.Linux.md) should do the trick. They'll guide you through downloading and building V8 yourself.

If that doesn't work, please be more specific about what you tried. "numerous methods found online" is, obviously, not a very precise description.

Comment: I've edited the initial question to show the tutorials I've tried to follow and what I've managed to do now, giving me a different error.  Please take a look at it

Comment: I don't know CentOS and I have no idea what `ea-php74-pecl` is or does. The instructions say that if you copied V8 to `/opt/v8`, you need to then specify that path for v8js, as in: `./configure --with-v8js=/opt/v8 ...`. So I'd suggest you try to find out how to pass extra options to `ea-php74-pecl`, or see if you can sidestep that tool and just install v8js manually like the documentation says. Or you could file an issue at github.com/phpv8/v8js and ask for help there.